# Conditional query on Spring Data JPA gives a -417 error on DB2 (z/OS)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, db2-zos

I currently have the following method signature in a Spring Data CrudRepository:

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Table c WHERE (:paramOne is null or c.fieldOne = :paramOne) AND (:paramTwo is null or c.fieldTwo = :paramTwo)")
    Iterable<Table> findByParamOneAndParamTwo(@Param("paramOne") Integer p1, @Param("paramTwo") Integer p2);
```

This gets translated by Hibernate to (simplified):

```
select * where (? is null or fieldOne=?) and (? is null or fieldTwo=?)
```

I use this to get a method that can both filter the table and return all the records.

My problem is that when I try and execute the repository's method I get a negative 417 (-417) Db2 error. Googling it says that it means

> A statement string to be prepared includes parameter markers as the operands of the same operator (for example: ? > ?)

even though my Hibernate query is not doing that.

Comment: You probably don't want to do `:paramOne is null` but rather `c.fieldOne is null`. Same goes for second parameter

Comment: No, the point of the query is that both p1 and p2 can be either a valid Integer or null, and if they are both null the query returns what's basically a findAll

Comment: Is that the actual query that is sent to dbms in your question? Is there a possibility that somewhere down the line it transforms the written query and feeds db something different?

Comment: That's the query that Hibernate prints when spring.jpa.show-sql is set to true, so Hibernate should be replacing the question marks with the parameters that are passed to the method

Comment: Hibernate shows the SQL with the placeholders. It replaces the HQL part with actual SQL. The parameter binding happens in the trace part of the logging

Comment: Hey I just tried running the program with Hibernate logging in trace mode, and passing 5 and 2 as p1 and p2 respectively. Hibernate binds 5 to parameter 1 and 2 and it binds 2 to parameter 3 and 4

Comment: may be you should use `Criteria` for dynamic query!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to push the logic, for checking whether or not the parms are null, up to the application since parameter markers are not supported in the NULL predicate: 'A parameter marker must not be specified for or within the expression.' (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_nullpredicate.html).  The message text for the SQLCODE -417 could be improved.